# How to configure the SQLServer UTCDATE to be the same as the Windows Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, utc

I have a table that one of those columns displays a datetime value:

```
--result when querying the database directly:
id    datetime
1     2019-05-29 05:12:06.000
2     2019-01-29 10:48:34.000
```

But through a web browser, such values are **+3 hours**:

```
--values when displayed in a Primefaces datatable from the Web Server:
id    datetime
1     2019-05-29 08:12:06.000
2     2019-01-29 13:48:34.000
```

I've researched and realized that this +3 hours is ocurring in the SQL Server:

```
SELECT GETDATE()   : 2019-06-19 11:48:53.483
SELECT GETUTCDATE(): 2019-06-19 14:48:53.483
```

About the GETUTCDATE, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): *This value is derived from the operating system of the **computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running**.*

But I've checked the OS time zone and seems to be ok:

[image: image showing the SQLServer GETDATE, GETUTCDATE and Windows Server time zone]

The SQLServer instance and the Windows Server are installed in a VM.

How can I configure the UTC Date in SQL Server to be the same as the OS, avoiding this +3 hours as described above ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi.  Your question is a bit confusing and too broad.  Are you asking about SQL Server? Or Java? Or Windows? Or GlassFish? Or PrimeFaces?  You may be using all of these things, but it's not clear at precisely how, or which is related to your question.  You may do well to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the Stack Overflow help center.  Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, even if the old question have had 1 up vote, I've reformulated it since I've found that it is a UTCDATE issue. Can you help me ?

Comment: GETDATE() =<UTC_DATE> - <SERVER_TZ_OFFSET(-3)> = <UTC_DATE> - 3 Hours

Comment: Hi JMarcel.  Happy to help - that's what we're here for.  But again, you've simply shown that your SQL Server and operating system are behaving correctly.  `GETDATE` returns the local time and `GETUTCDATE` returns the UTC time.  If you want them to be the same, you'd have to set your system time zone to UTC instead of Brasilia.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand about UTC?  UTC is [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  It is the time standard that regulates clocks.  It is the same all over the world simultaneously.  It is not any different in Brasil than it is in China or New York or Australia.   Thus, assuming your computer's clock is correctly synchronized to some source (a domain controller or Internet time server), then UTC time will always come out the same.  It's the local time that can vary.  The system time zone controls by how much.

Comment: @Matt Johnson, but Brasilia UTC is the correct one to use. I wonder if the GETUTCDATE is obtained from the host-PC where the VM is installed, maybe? If I change the UTC to Brasilia in the host-PC, that should work ? What do you think ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Brasilia UTC".  There is just UTC.  You seem to have the logic inverted.  Your computer coordinates time with other computers and keeps track of time in terms of UTC.  Then - for display on the taskbar, command line, etc. it applies the time zone to determine the local time to show.  GETUTCDATE is giving you the clock value before a time zone is applied.  GETDATE is giving you the converted local time after applying the time zone.

Comment: As far as VMs go, typically the host is responsible for synchronizing UTC to an external source, and then the guest gets its UTC time from the host.  Each one can apply a different time zone if they like, without affecting the other.  (In Windows + Hyper-V, this is done via the "VMIC Time Provider".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure the UTC Date in SQL Server to be the same as the OS, avoiding this +3 hours as described above ?

As discussed in the question comments, the UTC date and time is not the one that can be changed.  Only the local date and time can be changed, by changing the system time zone.  If you want them to be the same value, then change the system time zone to "(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time".

The only way around that would be to set the clock manually instead of synchronizing it, and to lie about the actual time.  This is not recommended, as many things require accurate time to work correctly.

Comment: As I found in this [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/993fe4d6-6e77-44aa-9ed4-98e0d21e48bf/how-to-change-the-default-sql-time-zone-to-gmt-0300?forum=transactsql), in the OS in the VM, I changed the UTC-Brasilia to UTC- Coordinate Universal Time, then manually adjusted the time clock and now GETDATE and GETUTCDATE are equal. But even doing this, the +3 hours still displayed through the Java web app. So I've set the JVM to: -`Duser.timezone=UTC` and now it is working as expected !

Comment: You shouldn't manually adjust the clock.  Set time automatically from a trusted source (domain controller, internet time server, etc.)